# Terraform RDS database credential

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws, aws-secrets-manager

In my Terraform code, i am using the aws_secretsmanager_secret_version data source to read this secret:

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "creds" {
# write your secret name here
  secret_id = "your_secret"
}
```

parse the secret from JSON, using jsondecode :

```
locals {
     your_secret = jsondecode(
                    data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.creds.secret_string
                  )

}
```

Now pass the secret to RDS:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "example" {
  engine               = "engine"
  engine_version       = "version"
  instance_class       = "instance"
  name                 = "example"
  # Set the secrets from AWS Secrets Manager
  username = local.your_secret.username
  password = local.your_secret.password
}
```

However, while running the same i am getting below error:

> Error: Error in function call
> on modules/rds/main.tf line 74, in locals:
> 74:   db-cred = jsondecode(
> 75:     data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.cred.secret_string
> 76:     )
> ├────────────────
> │ while calling jsondecode(str)

> Call to function "jsondecode" failed: invalid character '\n' in string
> literal.

Comment: What is the ***exact*** raw contents of your secret? It appear to contain a newline where it is not allowed.

Comment: I think you cannot break the function call into more than one line, i.e., it should be `your_secret = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.creds.secret_string)`.

Comment: thanks for help!! it's solved...it was a mistake in adding secrets in secret manager in aws console.